# What is the difference between THIS scope and APPLICATION scope in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, scope, coldfusion-9

Today I was reading a blog [Difference between THIS and APPLICATION scope](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/2/11/Two-quick-Applicationcfc-questions). What explained their I understood , After that i declared a variable in my Application.cfc in THIS scope, I am able to access that variable in all of my pages. So my question is Can we use THIS scope for declaring application level variables? OR Is there any more difference between THIS  and APPLICATION scoped variables.
Example:
Application.cfc

```
<cfset THIS.testVar1 = 50>
<cfset APPLICATION.testVar1 = 100>
```

Index.cfm

```
<cfdump var="#THIS.testVar1#"> O/P: 50
<cfdump var="#APPLICATION.testVar2#"> O/P: 100
```

So this leads to think me that both the scopes are similar. Please let me know if  something more difference is there between these scopes.

Comment: When you use the `THIS` scope in Application.cfc to set a variable, you are not actually storing it in the Application scope. That code would get processed on EVERY page request.

Comment: @ScottStroz: Processed means?

Comment: If you have something like `<cfset this.stuff = 'moo' />` in the psuedo-constructor that line of code gets executed with with every page request. However, if you set an Application scope variable the correct way (such as in `onApplictionStart()` there are other ways, but this is very common) it will only get run when you when the application starts or if you have logic in your app that re-initializes the application.

Answer (score 2):

`This` scope in Application.cfc is for setting cf application settings and shall be read using https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/GetApplicationMetadata in cf10.

`This` scope for ordinary cfc is for storing public functions and public attributes.

`Application` scope is for storing and fetching pieces of data, usually app configs and instance of singletons. It lives until the cf application timeout, or stopped, or server restarted.